# What are the contents of protactor.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was just going through the angular.js documentation **[HERE](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude)** and saw the section called:

> Multi-slot transclusion

and the following code in the protractor.js tab:

```
it('should have transcluded the title and the body', function() {
  var titleElement = element(by.model('title'));
  titleElement.clear();
  titleElement.sendKeys('TITLE');
  var textElement = element(by.model('text'));
  textElement.clear();
  textElement.sendKeys('TEXT');
  expect(element(by.binding('title')).getText()).toEqual('TITLE');
  expect(element(by.binding('text')).getText()).toEqual('TEXT');
});
```

I was just wondering if thats angular's version of jQuery

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [E2E](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing) section of angular.js site:

> Protractor is a Node.js program, and runs end-to-end tests that are also written in JavaScript and run with node. Protractor uses WebDriver to control browsers and simulate user actions.