# How to save map values locally for the users secound time visit

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I was just going through an example of openlayers3 , where a users location is retrived when he clicks on the locate me button , see demo **[HERE](http://purplefront.net/find-geo-location/)** , I am using openlayers3 and basically the code for this tiny demo is below here:

```
// Geolocation Control
var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation(/** @type {olx.GeolocationOptions} */ ({
    projection: view.getProjection(),
    trackingOptions: {
        maximumAge: 10000,
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 600000
    }
}));

var deltaMean = 500; // the geolocation sampling period mean in ms

// Listen to position changes
geolocation.on('change', function(evt) {
    var position = geolocation.getPosition();
    var accuracy = geolocation.getAccuracy();
    var heading = geolocation.getHeading() || 0;
    var speed = geolocation.getSpeed() || 0;
    var m = Date.now();

    addPosition(position, heading, m, speed);

    var coords = positions.getCoordinates();
    var len = coords.length;
    if (len >= 2) {
        deltaMean = (coords[len - 1][3] - coords[0][3]) / (len - 1);
    }

    var html = [
        'Position: ' + position[0].toFixed(2) + ', ' + position[1].toFixed(2),
        'Accuracy: ' + accuracy,
        'Heading: ' + Math.round(radToDeg(heading)) + '&deg;',
        'Speed: ' + (speed * 3.6).toFixed(1) + ' km/h',
        'Delta: ' + Math.round(deltaMean) + 'ms'
    ].join('<br />');
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = html;
});
```

it can also be seen **[HERE](http://purplefront.net/find-geo-location/js/geolocation.js)**

Now i would like to make it such that when i user clicks the "geolocated me!" button the 1st time around, all the details are persisted, I.E. when the user revists the demo and clicks the button again, the values of his previous visit should be persisted, i know localstorage and cookies can be used in JS for persistence , but i am not quite sure which parts of **[THIS](http://purplefront.net/find-geo-location/js/geolocation.js)** script should be persisted and which should be not , can anybody give me a clue ? , what values would i have to store locally so that when the user clicks the "geolocate me!" button the secound time around , the values are retrived locally from his machine rather than there being a lag.

I beleive i would have to use localstorage somewhere in the below functions:

```
// Geolocation Control
var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation(/** @type {olx.GeolocationOptions} */ ({
    projection: view.getProjection(),
    trackingOptions: {
        maximumAge: 10000,
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 600000
    }
}));

var deltaMean = 500; // the geolocation sampling period mean in ms

// Listen to position changes
geolocation.on('change', function(evt) {
    var position = geolocation.getPosition();
    var accuracy = geolocation.getAccuracy();
    var heading = geolocation.getHeading() || 0;
    var speed = geolocation.getSpeed() || 0;
    var m = Date.now();

    addPosition(position, heading, m, speed);

    var coords = positions.getCoordinates();
    var len = coords.length;
    if (len >= 2) {
        deltaMean = (coords[len - 1][3] - coords[0][3]) / (len - 1);
    }

    var html = [
        'Position: ' + position[0].toFixed(2) + ', ' + position[1].toFixed(2),
        'Accuracy: ' + accuracy,
        'Heading: ' + Math.round(radToDeg(heading)) + '&deg;',
        'Speed: ' + (speed * 3.6).toFixed(1) + ' km/h',
        'Delta: ' + Math.round(deltaMean) + 'ms'
    ].join('<br />');
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = html;
});
```

Comment: I looked into firebug and the geolocation object seems to have property names obfuscated, what is that supposed to be?

Comment: i don't see that in chrome

Comment: I mean names like `B`, `C`... etc. Anyway I was playing with the demo and I think I have a solution, except one thing - the map refuses to update until I click it.

Comment: yes thats the way its supposed to be , except when i click the button the secound time , i want everything tobbe fetched from the users localstorage . (it should't take that extra half secound to load)

Comment: Bad idea, don't you think? If user moves around, they will not be able to get their current position, instead they get cached position.

Comment: what you say is absolutly true ... but thats also exactly what i want :)

Comment: [You should actually accept the answers once you consider them helful.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33290832/607407)

Comment: i will .. in a while:)

Comment: I am talking about the question in link. You're actually creating noise in *Unanswered* section by not accepting answers that are complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should alter `geolocation` position directly if you use cached values. I also don't think you should remember anything apart from location, because both `accuracy`, `speed` and heading change so often any cached value is totally irrelevant.

You can modify my input to your needs, but I am convinced the best way to handle this matter is to load last user location on page load. I use this to save last location to `localStorage`:

```
geolocation.addEventListener("change", function() {
     localStorage["lastPosition"] = this.getPosition().join(",");
});
```

And this somewhere on map load:

```
if(localStorage["lastPosition"]) {
    geolocation.set('position', localStorage["lastPosition"]
                    .split(",")                   // Split numbers
                    .map(function(x){return 1*x;})// Convert strings to numbers
    );
    geolocation.changed();
    map.render();
}
```

You could also add a button <kbd>Restore last location</kbd>, or use this in your <kbd>Geolocate me</kbd> button.

Call this to forget the position:

```
localStorage.removeItem("lastPosition");
```

Comment: zato , is there a way to load the map tiles only once ? i know this would be entitled to a totally different question .. but just asking !

Comment: @TenaliRaman I'm not even sure how are map tiles actually rendered. Look in the docs, they're rather extensive.